# How to move free space in front of APFS container?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, apfs

[image: diskutil list output]

How does one go about changing the starting position of an APFS partition on a drive? In this situation, I would like the 209.4 GB of free space to end up behind the APFS partition so that I can resize the Windows partition on the drive to be bigger. Above I have my current layout. Neither Disk Utility.app, gparted, or diskutil have shown to be useful in this process.

Comment: Please don't post text as an image; see [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Comment: Why is gparted not useful? [Gparted claims to be able to move APFS.](https://gparted.org/features.php)